# CUDA version checking issues

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia

I am using NVIDIA DGX A100 GPU.  I want to check my CUDA version.

I have downloaded CUDA 11.7 using `conda install -c nvidia cudatoolkit=11.7.0` . However, when I am checking through `nvcc --version` :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Sep_13_19:13:29_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.50
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30411180_0
```

When I use the command `conda list cudatoolkit` I get this output:

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cudatoolkit               11.7.0              hd8887f6_10    nvidia
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong? Also, are there any libraries I have to import?

Comment: You can have multiple CUDA versions installed on a single machine. And there are various methods to install CUDA, some of which will put the CUDA install in different places on your machine. When you "install CUDA" via conda, you are getting a portion of the CUDA toolkit tucked away in a particular conda environment. Probably will help if you understand what conda environments are.  When you do `nvcc --version` you are  checking on a CUDA toolkit install that is completely separate from whatever you did in or with conda. So you are getting a different answer as to the "installed CUDA version".

Answer (score 1):

`nvcc` is not included in `cudatoolkit`. You need to install the `nvcc` compiler with `conda install cuda-nvcc -c nvidia/label/cuda-11.7.0`.

More info: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#upgrading-from-cudatoolkit-package